# How to handle event in recursively nested component in angular2

Tags: angular, recursion, service, event-handling, observable

I am working on functionality where I need to add component recursively and I want an event which will be triggered by the nested component at any level but it get handled on the Main parent component(**appcomponent**) which added that component

where is my recursively adding **wts** comp html

```ts
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-body" *ngIf="rules">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addRule()">add rule</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addGroup()">add group</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeGroup()" *ngIf="enableRemoveGroup">remove group</button>
        <div *ngIf="rules.groups">
<!-- adding itself if there is group -->
            <wts *ngFor="let group of rules.groups" [data]="group"></wts>
        </div>
        <rule *ngFor="let rule of rules.rules" [rule]="rule"></rule>
    </div>
```

wts component .ts

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'wts',
    templateUrl: './wts.component.html',
    providers: [WtsServiceService],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class WTSComponent implements OnInit {
    rules: Group;
    enableRemoveGroup: boolean = false;
    @Output() removeGroupCB = new EventEmitter();
    @Input('data')
    set data(value) {
        if (value) {
            this.enableRemoveGroup = true;
        }
        this.rules = value || new Group();
    };
    constructor(private wtsServiceService: WtsServiceService) {
        this.rules = new Group();
    }
    private addGroup() {
        if (!this.rules.groups) {
            this.rules.groups = [];
        }
        this.rules.groups.push(new Group());
        console.log(this.rules);
    }
    private removeGroup() {
        delete this.rules;
    }
    private addRule() {
        this.rules.rules.push(new Rule());
    }
    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

In my comp I have object **rules** which contain the rules and groups, and group contains rule and group

here is my model

```ts
export class Rule {
    subjectType: string;
    valueType: string;
    subject: string;
    value: string;
    constructor(st = '', vt = '', s = '', v = '') {
        this.subjectType = st;
        this.valueType = vt;
        this.subject = s;
        this.value = v;
    }
}
export class Group {
    rules: Rule[];
    groups: Group[];
    constructor() {
        this.rules = [];
        this.rules.push(new Rule());
    }
};
```

If we have group withing group then it nested itself to form the UI. and we have rule component to list rules

here is my rule comp .ts

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'rule',
  templateUrl: './rule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rule.component.css'],
  providers: [WtsServiceService],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class RuleComponent implements OnInit {
  rule: Rule;
  @Input('rule')
  set Setrule(value) {
    this.rule = value;
  }
  constructor(private wtsServiceService: WtsServiceService) { }

  private triggerHanlder() {
    this.wtsServiceService.triggerCallBack();// to trigger appcomponent function
  }
}
```

here is my rule comp .html

```ts
<p *ngIf="rule">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="triggerHanlder()">trigger handler</button>
</p>
```

which will trigger an event when user select a valid rule and get handled by main component ie **appcomponent**

To do that I have created on service which returns observable which is subscribed on appcomponent and rule component call a function to trigger that event but its now working as expected.

here is my service

```ts
@Injectable()
export class WtsServiceService {
  resultSubject: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);
  constructor() { }
  public handleCallBack() {
    return this.resultSubject;
  }
  public triggerCallBack() {
    this.resultSubject.next({});
  }
}
```

here is my appcomponent

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  constructor( private _wtsServiceService: WtsServiceService) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._wtsServiceService.handleCallBack().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('parent function');//this should get execute when user click on trigger handler on rule comp
    })
  }
}
```

**appcomp > wts > wts > wts >...> rule (here I have to emit an event and should get handled on appcomp. this rule compo may at any level)**

Please help to find the workaround and suggest if there is any other better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the root `wts` component a different component `root-wts` (can have the same template as the nested `wts` component, provide a service that that is injected to every `wts` and `rule` and also `root-wts`.

`root-wts` subscribes to an observable in this service
`wts` (if applicable) and `rule` emit events using the observable in the shared service

Comment: yes, same thing I am also trying to do but not working for me I have called triggerCallBack function of service from rule comp and subscribe handleCallBack on app comp

Comment: I think the problem is that you provide the service on every component and therefore you get as many service instances as component instances. You should provide it only once on a component that is only instantiated once or on a module (to make it application-wide singleton).

Comment: Yes, I think it's fine.

Comment: its now working if I added multiple time on same component

Comment: Its get trigger all of the component

Comment: What do you add multiple times on the same component?

Comment: wts component(which add itself recursively)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Can you please edit your question and add the code there that demonstrates what you try to accomplish?

Comment: appcomp >|-> wts > wts > wts >...> rule 
                  |-> wts > wts > wts >...> rule 

this way I will add wts component multiple times on app component so I will have two brach but due to single tone service event emited by any brach it get trigger for both branch

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you try to explain. What is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631764/how-to-communicate-bet-component-using-service